# find '== text ==' with regex

Tags: python, regex

I just can't figure out how to find all '== foo ==' without getting all the '==== bar ===='. Using `^={2}.*={2}$` doesn't work for some reason. Maybe because i want to find multiple strings like '== foo ==' within one text.

for example:

```
"== foo ==
lorem ipsum
== bar == 
==== bar ===="
```

should only return `== foo ==` and `== bar ==`

Comment: Where are you using the regex? What is the code you are using it in?

Comment: python's re module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add negative look-arounds for extra `=`:

```
(?<!=)== \w+ ==(?!=)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/7u7590/2

Comment: There is a small typo - it should be `(?<!=)`, not `(?!<=)`.